# Back in time on Natty

Tags: 11.04, backup

Since Ubuntu's Maverick release I had been using [Back In Time](http://backintime.le-web.org/) for my backup needs. Now I see that it's not updated for Natty in their [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~bit-team/+archive/stable). When I searched in the Synaptic, I saw a new version of 'Back In Time' with Maintainers as Ubuntu Developers . So can I expect future support for Back In Time from Ubuntu developers or do I need to wait for PPA to be updated?

Comment: not an answer but you can use the version that's on the ppa for maverick, just make sure that when added chnage from natty to maverick, you can do this by editing the software sources

Comment: @Uri, tried that but got an error saying such a resource is not available.

Comment: if you search it through synaptic, does it still give you the error?

Comment: In synaptic the package was available but when I looked at properties I noted that it is maintained by Ubuntu Developers. I removed the PPA from my sources and reloaded the package list. Still the synaptic version is there.

Comment: try with that one?

Comment: Have installed it! Asked the question to know if someone knows about the future of that particular PPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would send them an email, [bit-contributors](https://launchpad.net/~bit-contibutors)

Comment: I had tried contacting the team's owner few days ago through launchpad but got no response.